# Calculating Combinations for a 7 digit binary number

Tags: c#, for-loop, combinations

I am trying to calculate all the Combinations of a 7 digit number. Each digit can occupy basically two values that's why I am calling it a binary number.

The digit are represented by FNMSDPL. Basically I want all the combinations of values and their sum.

I wrote the below code but its not working.

```
        F[0] = 9.29;
        F[1] = -4.47;
        N[0] = 9.64;
        N[1] = -5.77;
        M[0]= -7.48;
        M[1] = -2.13;
        S[0] = 25.85;
        S[1]= -3.55;
        D[0]= 12.14;
        D[1] = -4.90;
        P[0] = 8.65;
        P[1]= -0.85;
        L[0] = 9.14;
        L[1]= -1.73;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 2; k++)
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++)
                        {
                            for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
                            {
                                for (int o = 0; 0 < 2; o++)
                                {
                                    double  count = F[i] + M[j] + L[k] + S[l] + D[m] + P[n] + L[o];
                                    System.Console.WriteLine(count);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Error Message:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I am getting the above error at "double count =" line.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean when you say "It's not working." You might want to step through the code in a debugger. That should reveal one issue immediately.

Comment: Instead of providing code express with an example that what do you means by *"Combinations for a 7 digit binary number"*

Comment: One definite error is the line `for (int o = 0; 0 < 2; o++)`. `0 < 2` is always true -> infinite loop. We learn from this not to use `o` as variable name because it is easy to getting confused with `0`.

Comment: @halex A great demonstration of the reason to use good variable names, or at least a reason to never use `l (el)` (is it a one???) or `o (oh)` for variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font selection on Stack Overflow may have resolved this one

```
for (int o = 0; 0 < 2; o++)
```

The condition should be using `o` instead of `0`. (Tip: avoid using `o` or `O` as variable names.)

Edit: Another problem here (should be incrementing `l`, not `k`):

```
for (int l = 0; l < 2; k++)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this won't work as expected:

```
for (int l = 0; l < 2; k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use something more clever than 7 nested `for` loops (since, as the other answers point out, this is terribly prone to error, especially when you have to make up 14 variable names). A recursive solution would do nicely here.

As for the sum, you don't need to generate all possibilities to know the sum of all 128 possible numbers. Observe that each binary digit (0 or 1) occurs exactly 64 times in each slot, so the sum total is just 64 times the sum of the 14 floats in your arrays.

Comment: New to programming. No idea about recursive solution. All I know id for loop.

Comment: Also, I did not understand how you calculated the sum. How 64?

Comment: There are 128 'binary numbers' with 7 digits. For a given position, half have 0, half have 1 in that position.